# What is the probability that a randomly chosen student plays a winter or spring sport?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $10\%$ of all students play a winter sport, $20\%$ play a spring sport, and $5\%$ play both a winter and spring sport. What is the probability that a randomly chosen student plays a winter or spring sport?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$$

Where $P(A)$ is the probability for winter / spring; $P(A \cup B)$ is the union, namely the probability for both winter and spring and $P(A \cap B)$ is the probability for the OR events.

So:

$$P(A\cap B) = 10 + 20 - 5 = 25\%$$

Answer (score 0):

10% of all students play a winter sport and 5% of students play both spring and winter sports. Then 5% of students only play a winter sport.

20% of students play a spring sport and 5% of students play both spring and winter sports. Then 15% of students only play a spring sport.

So 5% only play a winter sport, 5% play both winter and spring sports, and 15% only play a spring sport. Therefore, 25% of students play at least one winter or spring sport. The other 75% of students play neither winter nor spring sports.